# Android VM as Developing Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I've downloaded the Android VM (http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/27/download-android-os-to-run-in-a-virtual-machine/) and running this in VirtualBox. 
This is working fine.

I want to write my app in Eclipse and when I have to test it I want to you use the Android VM as my emulator instead of the default emulator.

When I start the Android VM my internet is working but my question now is how do I attach Eclipse to the Android VM?

Basicly : 
Eclipse > Run Application > Start in Android VM (Instead of An Android AVD)

Comment: Run the following: `adb connect 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect it to adb (which is in the android SDK's platform-tools folder) by opening a terminal and typing:

```
adb connect <ip_address_of_the_vm>
```

To find out the IP address of the VM, install a terminal emulator on the android VM and type:

```
ifconfig
```